# ansible vault with private key as password (similar to eyaml)?

Tags: ansible, private-key, ansible-vault

Part of puppet to ansible migration.
current puppet config uses eyaml:

```
:eyaml:
  :datadir: /opt/puppet/yamls
  :pkcs7_private_key: /opt/puppet/secure/keys/eyaml_private_key.pkcs7.pem
  :pkcs7_public_key:  /opt/puppet/public/eyaml_public_key.pkcs7.pem
  :extension: 'yaml'
```

Ansible has vault which achieves the encryption, but from what I have understood so far, it requires storing password as plain text in a file.

Can I use key combination similar to eyaml for ansible vault?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that ansible-vault only supports use of a password as an encryption key.

[Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) has a pluggable authentication system, and one of the built-in options [uses PEM-format certs](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/cert.html).  There is [a simple plugin](https://github.com/jhaals/ansible-vault) that integrtes Vault with Ansible.  Vault also offers a number of other advantages over a shared-encrypted-file approach, but that's a larger topic that's not suited for here.

Answer (score 1):

> from what I have understood so far, it requires storing password as plain text in a file.

Not quite correct. You can [pass executable](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html#running-a-playbook-with-vault) path as `--vault-password-file` value.
So you can have some script that will do any sort of password management and just print the key to stdout (that will be piped as vault password to Ansible).